# Container-Fluid Not Using Full Width of The Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, containers

I am trying to create a page with a collapsible sidebar on the left and a content are that occupies the rest of the page. In my content area I want a navbar up on top and the rest of the content below.

Currently, I am using a `container-fluid` class to make sure the navbar resizes. When I have a regular paragraph encapsulated in `<p>` tag the navbar and the paragraph spans the full width of the page. However, the moment I use `row`'s and `col`'s the content seems to take up only have the page and does not go to the edges.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="content">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn navbar-btn">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
                    <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/account-settings">username</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- I have a few divs here -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <!-- I have a fre more divs here -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- row -->      

</div>
```

I am currently using Bootstrap 3 (3.3.7) and was following along with [this tutorial.](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar) I know there are a few other questions on Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions there seems to do anything to solve my problem.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your rows aren't within a container.

Comment: @BillyMoat, I just tried tried that. Unfortunately, on my desktop that makes it wider, but still not to the end of the page; and on my smaller laptop screen its too wide and causes a horizontal scroll bar to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you expecting this. if it's not your expectation please add fiddler snippet here, I will update code.

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
                theme: "minimal"
            });

            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                $('#sidebar, #content').toggleClass('active');
                $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
                $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            });
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/style2.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css"/>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li><a href="#" class="download">Download source</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="article">Back to article</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content Holder -->
        <div id="content" class="">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                            <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div style="background-color: #324D5C; padding: 25px; border-radius: 5px;">
                        <p><b style="color: #fff;">Upcomming</b></p>
                        <h1 style="color: #46B29D; text-align: right;">50</h1>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div style="background-color: #46B29D; padding: 25px; border-radius: 5px;">
                        <p><b style="color: #fff;">Total Created</b></p>
                        <h1 style="color: #F0CA4D; text-align: right;">120</h1>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div style="background-color: #F0CA4D; padding: 25px; border-radius: 5px;">
                        <p><b style="color: #E37B40;">Avgerage Value</b></p>
                        <h1 style="color: #324D5C; text-align: right;">$400</h1>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div> <!-- col-md-3 -->

                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div style="background-color: #46B29D; padding: 25px; border-radius: 5px;">
                        <p><b style="color: #fff;">Upcomming</b></p>
                        <h1 style="color: #46B29D; text-align: right;">50</h1>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div style="background-color: #46B29D; padding: 25px; border-radius: 5px; ">
                        <p><b style="color: #fff;">Total Created</b></p>
                        <h1 style="color: #F0CA4D; text-align: right;">120</h1>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div style="background-color: #F0CA4D; padding: 25px; border-radius: 5px;">
                        <p><b style="color: #E37B40;">Avgerage Value</b></p>
                        <h1 style="color: #324D5C; text-align: right;">$400</h1>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div> <!-- col-md-9 -->
            </div><!-- row -->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately, I think there might be something else in my code getting in the way.Here is a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/gtjkyzb6/8/) of exactly what I'm working with. Sorry, if it seems untidy, html/css is far from my wheel-house.

Comment: I have updated code in my example above, go through that.